# SQL Server Adding a Where clause into a view?

Tags: sql-server, date, where-clause

I have this view:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_HoursTakenPerEmployee] AS
SELECT e.[EmployeeID], 
       COALESCE(SUM(hrf.[HoursTaken]), 0) AS HoursTaken
FROM [dbo].[Employee] e LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[HolidayRequestForm] hrf
      ON e.[EmployeeID] = hrf.[EmployeeID]
GROUP BY e.[EmployeeID];
GO
```

The holidayRequestform table looks something like this.

```
 EmployeeID  | HoursTaken     | YearRequested  | MonthRequested |
 ------------+----------------+ ---------------+----------------+
 1           | 8              | 2018           |06
 1           | 16             | 2019           |01
 2           | 8              | 2019           |01
 3           | 8              | 2018           |01
```

When I select the view, the results are as follows:

```
EmployeeID|HoursTaken
----------+----------
 1        |24
 2        |8
 3        |8
```

However I would like to only have the view Calculate the hoursTaken for the current year (2019) while still keeping the records of the previous years.

I have tried inserting a `WHERE YearRequested = YEAR(GETDATE())` clause in the view but I'm unsure where I would place it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_HoursTakenPerEmployee] AS
SELECT e.[EmployeeID], 
       COALESCE(SUM(hrf.[HoursTaken]), 0) AS HoursTaken
FROM [dbo].[Employee] e LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[HolidayRequestForm] hrf
      ON e.[EmployeeID] = hrf.[EmployeeID]
WHERE hrf.YearRequested = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY e.[EmployeeID];
GO
```

** just a tip for your view's name. Give it a name that indicates the year filter

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_HoursTakenPerEmployee] AS
SELECT e.[EmployeeID], 
       COALESCE(SUM(hrf.[HoursTaken]), 0) AS HoursTaken
FROM [dbo].[Employee] e LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[HolidayRequestForm] hrf
      ON e.[EmployeeID] = hrf.[EmployeeID]
WHERE YearRequested = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY e.[EmployeeID];
GO
```

--SELECT CLAUSE in SQL is in this order

```
SELECT
Columns
FROM TABLEA 
WHERE 
GROUP BY
ORDER BY
```